# How can you deploy ARM templates from Github using azure runbooks?

Tags: azure, github

Im using azure runbooks with powershell and want to deploy a template from  my github repository. Ive tried the command:

**New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName 'rg01'  -TemplateUri -$templateuricode**

(the $templateuricode contains the url link to the github json file )

but getting an error  - "unable to download content from 'https://github.com/myfolder/myproject/blob/
test.json'. The tracking Id is '0216a103-a683-461e-ae9d-785d9f6efc4c'. Please 
see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage details.

Answer (score 1):

I worked it out, you need to select the RAW button in github where your JSON file is then copy that link and place that after -TemplateUri

eg New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName 'test'  -TemplateUri "place the link from github here"

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely with the fact github requires TLS 1.2 you can work around using this command right before deploying:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

Comment: would i insert the above into powershell  before the New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment command?

Comment: yes, looking at the error text this is the most likely source of the issue

Comment: i just tried that and same error                                                                                              
------------                                                                                           ---.
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : InvalidContentLink: Unable to download deployment content from 
'https://github.com/myproject/test.json'. The tracking Id is 
'739e35d3-8c72-4be1-b3ff-66c990a45689'. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage details.